# L-series: Which logarithm will split this product into a sum?

Tags: logarithms, analytic-number-theory, infinite-product

For a project, I am analyzing a proof of [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions.). It is my first introduction to the concept of an $L$-series, which is defined by
\begin{align*}
L(s,\chi) = \sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{\chi(n)}{n^s},
\end{align*}
for a character $\chi$ and a real number $s>1$. Using Euler's product representation, we see
\begin{align*}
L(s,\chi) = \prod_p \frac{1}{1-(\chi(p) \text{/} p^s)}.
\end{align*}
(The product is taken over primes.) In the proof I am reading, the author goes on to say that we may take a logarithm here, giving
\begin{align*}
\log L(s,\chi) = -\sum_p \log\bigg(1-\frac{\chi(p)}{  p^s}\bigg).
\end{align*}
However, I am struggling to understand which logarithm they are using, as we are dealing with complex numbers, and the log of an infinite product will not split into a sum under specific circumstances (this depends on which branch of the complex logarithm we decide to use.) My question is: are there properties of characters that allow us to choose a specific log here? (which one?) Otherwise, is there another way of getting around this issue?

Comment: We are using $-\log(1-z) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k}$ for $|z| < 1$. This gives us a Dirichlet series $G(s)=\sum_{p^k} \frac{\chi(p^k)}{k} p^{-sk}$ such that $L(s,\chi) = e^{G(s)}$ for $\Re(s) > 1$.

Comment: Ah, this is very clear. I appreciate the help

Comment: The issue here is more delicate that you appreciate. The "logarithm of $L(s,\chi)$" on the left side should *not* be defined by the right side: that equality is a theorem, not a definition. There is a theorem in complex analysis that a nonvanishing holomorphic function $f(s)$ on a simply connected region $\Omega$ has a logarithm, i.e., a holomorphic solution $g(s)$ to $e^{g(s)} = f(s)$ on $\Omega$, and this is defined up to an integer multiple of $2\pi i$. By the hard fact that $L(1,\chi) \not= 0$ and continuity, $L(s,\chi)$ is holomorphic and nonvanishing on the union of [contd.]

Comment: the half-plane  ${\rm Re}(s) > 1$  and an open disc around $s = 1$. That's a simply connected region $\Omega$, and since $L(s,\chi) \rightarrow 1$ as $s \rightarrow \infty$ along the real line (or even as ${\rm Re}(s) \rightarrow \infty$) we might *define* $\log L(s,\chi)$ to be the solution to $e^{g(s)} = L(s,\chi)$ on $\Omega$ such that $g(s) \rightarrow 0$ as $s \rightarrow \infty$ on the real line. This gives a meaning to $\log L(s,\chi)$ on all of $\Omega$. The series over primes you see on the right side, where $-\log(1-z)$ for $|z| < 1$ is defined by the usual power series, is [contd.]

Comment: also a logarithm of $L(s,\chi)$ just to the right of $s = 1$. These two logarithms of $L(s,\chi)$ near $s = 1$, one coming from general principles of complex analysis and the other from writing down an infinite series, must differ by an integral multiple of $2\pi i$ and thus we can correct the definition of $\log L(s,\chi)$ by an additive constant to achieve the desired equality you are puzzling over.  The point of having an independent construction of $\log L(s,\chi)$ on the left is that we'd like to say after expanding the right side that $\sum_p \chi(p)/p^s$ for ${\rm Re}(s) >1$ [contd.]

Comment: has an analytic continuation to a neighborhood of $s = 1$ so it has a meaningful limit as $s \rightarrow 1^+$.  Without a separate construction of the logarithm of $L(s,\chi)$ on the left side around $s = 1$, how do you really show $\sum_{p} \chi(p)/p^s$ has a limit as $s \rightarrow 1^+$? Most accounts of this are too hand-wavy on this point for my taste.

Comment: @KCd thanks for the explanation. I'm still curious how the equality comes about. Can you please explain why you end up with $log L(s,\chi)$ (as you defined it) equalling $-\sum_p \log(1-\frac{\chi(p)}{p^s})$

Comment: Any two logarithms of a nonvanishing holomorphic function on a domain differ by an integer multiple of $2\pi i$, so if you start by defining $\log L(s,\chi)$ on the union of $\text{Re}(s) > 1$ together with a small open disc around $1$ using complex analysis (an integral of $L'(s,\chi)/L(s,\chi)$ from a fixed point in the domain out to a variable endpoint in the domain, plus a fixed number to make its exponential come out to $L(s,\chi)$ rather than a constant multiple of that) then you have one logarithm of the $L$-function. That infinite series you wrote down is a logarithm of the [contd]

Comment: $L$-function for $\text{Re}(s) > 1$ but not obviously anywhere else. On that half plane both constructions of logarithms make direct sense, so there they differ by a constant, some integer multiple of $2\pi i$. The construction of a logarithm using contour integrals was only defined up to adding an integer multiple of $2\pi i$ anyway, so by adjusting the additive constant in the first construction we can make the two constructions agree on $\text{Re}(s) > 1$. This proves for $\text{Re}(s) > 1$ that $\sum_{p,k} \chi(p^k)/p^{ks} = c  + \int_{2}^s L'(w,\chi)/L(w,\chi) dw$ for some $c$ [contd.]

Comment: where I picked starting point $2$ for the path in the integral just arbitrarily (using a different base point would have changed the number $c$). The nice thing about the integral formulation is that it makes sense also on a small disc around $s=1$ where the $L$-function does not vanish. That proves the Dirichlet series definition of a logarithm of the $L$-function has an analytic continuation to a neighborhood of $s=1$. Since $\sum_{p,k\geq 2} \chi(p^k)/p^{ks}$, where we removed terms for $k=1$, actually converges absolutely for $\text{Re}(s) > 1/2$, it is holomorphic there and this [contd]

Comment: proves $\sum_p \chi(p)/p^s$ has an analytic continuation from $\text{Re}(s) > 1$ to a neighborhood of $s= 1$, so in particular the limit from the right $\lim_{s\rightarrow 1^+} \sum_p \chi(p)/p^s$ exists. I do not know a simpler way to prove this.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue in the book "Analytic number theory" by De Koninck and Luca (Eq. (14.6) on p.241).
Given the general style of the book and the preceding arguments of the proof, I highly doubt that the authors had
@KCd's argument (see comments) in mind. I can think of two ways to resolve the issue:

(1) Instead of looking at $\log L(s,\chi)$ directly, consider
$$\exp\Bigl(\sum_{p}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\chi(p^k)}{kp^{ks}}\Bigr)=\prod_{p}\exp\Bigl(\log\Bigl(\frac{1}{1-\chi(p)p^{-s}}\Bigr)\Bigr)=\prod_{p}\frac{1}{1-\chi(p)p^{-s}}=L(s,\chi).$$
The arguments apply to this equation similarly.

(2) To show that the original equation really holds for the principal branch of the complex logarithm (which I don't know at the moment), one must show that the imaginary part of $$\sum_p\log(1-\chi(p)p^{-s})$$ lies between $-\pi$ and $\pi$. Hence, we nee to compute the argument $\phi$ of $1-\chi(p)p^{-s}$. We may assume that $\chi(p)\ne 0$ (otherwise $\phi=0$). Then $\chi(p)$ is a root of unity, in particular $|\chi(p)|=1$. The number $1-\chi(p)p^{-s}$ lies on the circle described by $f(x)=\sqrt{p^{-2s}-(x-1)^2}$. Now $\phi$ is maximized for the point on the tangent crossing the origin. If $x$ denotes the real part of that point and $a$ denotes the slope of the tangent, we get the equations
$$ax=f(x),\qquad a=f'(x)=\frac{1-x}{f(x)}.$$
If I'm not mistaken, this yields $x=1-p^{-2s}$ and $\phi=\arctan(a)=\arctan(f(x)/x)=\mathrm{arccot}\sqrt{p^{2s}-1}$.
I don't know how to simplify this further, but I did some numerical experiments. It might indeed be the case that the claim holds. I have to admit that I'm a novice in analysis. Perhaps someone else can finish the computation.